# Google Maps API V3 - Drawing manager event listeners are fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps api v3. I have a drawing manager class event listener as follows

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function(polyline) {
      var val = (polyline.getPath().getArray());

   });
```

but the problem is this event is triggered multiple times. Is there any way around this. I want an even which is fired only once after drawing is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You probably registered the event listener multiple times.

The `polylinecomplete` listener is fired when a polyline is completed. The only way the event is triggered multiple times is when you have registered more of such listeners.

Whenever you call `google.maps.event.addListener()` a new listener is registered.
Check where where the listener registration code is placed and how many times its called.

Comment: I do have many other listeners as well, but specifically this callback function is triggered multiple times, I assume this callback function is triggered only for polylinecomplete event, for example. If I have a polyline of two Gpoints, then this function is triggered 4 times.

Comment: I know there are two events fired for a drawing manager '{overlay}complete' and 'overlaycomplete'

Comment: I didn't have any problem with the event. It always behaved as expected. Try debugging it using `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce()` instead, if the event is fired more than once, then there is some other problem.

Comment: ok thanks :). I am now just accepting the first call and ignoring the rest, until i figure out the problem.